# Validate duplicate rows / columns

Tags: r, validation, duplicates

I need to do data validation to identify is there any duplicates in CodeA1, CodeA2 and Code A3 (columns).

```
  CodeA1 CodeA2 CodeA3  
1   1     NA      5     
2   3     1       3     
3   8     3       3     
4   3     NA      NA     
5   4     1       2     
6   1     8       3
```

The rows in all columns (CodeA1, CodeA2, CodeA3) should be unique across.

Can somebody please help in R?

I would like to identify the duplicates across all the rows and have the result as below

```
  CodeA1 CodeA2 CodeA3  Duplicate
1   1     NA       5    No
2   3     1       3     Yes
3   8     3       3     Yes
4   3     NA      NA     No
5   4     1       2     No
6   1     8       3     No
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possibile solution is:

```
dtset$Duplicate <- apply(dtset,1,function(x) any(table(x)>1))

dtset

########
  CodeA1 CodeA2 CodeA3 Duplicate
1      1     NA      5     FALSE
2      3      1      3      TRUE
3      8      3      3      TRUE
4      3     NA     NA     FALSE
5      4      1      2     FALSE
6      1      8      3     FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks Marco. I'm exploring the apply() function. By using the solution that you post, I'm unable to identify the duplicates except for [2, ] (i got "FALSE". Is there any specific reasons for that?

Comment: Second row -> 

2      3      1      3      FALSE

Comment: the code is working for me. Is your data in `data.frame` format?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution using `apply` and `unique`. This will also identify a double NA as a duplicated, although you could modify it.

```
 mydf <-
     data.frame(
         CodeA1 = c(1, 3, 8, 3, 4, 1),
         CodeA2 = c(NA, 1, 3, NA, 1, 9),
         CodeA3 = c(5, 3, 3, NA, 2, 3)
     )
 mydf$duplicated <-
     apply(mydf[, 1:3], 1, function(x) {
         ifelse(length(unique(x, is.na  = T)) < length(x), TRUE, FALSE)
     })
 mydf

  CodeA1 CodeA2 CodeA3 duplicated
1      1     NA      5      FALSE
2      3      1      3       TRUE
3      8      3      3       TRUE
4      3     NA     NA       TRUE
5      4      1      2      FALSE
6      1      9      3      FALSE
```